# Image/2D array resampling in C

Tags: c, interpolation, downsampling

I am looking to implement a resampling algorithm for a 2D array(it could be grayscale image or some 2D array of floating point values).

The steps involved in this particular operation are:

1. Given a 2D array, I first downsample it to size of 8x8 or 16x16, using some down-sampling method(preferably with a preceeding anti-aliasing filtering).
2. Some nuemrical operation on this.
3. Then upsample it back to its original size by doing, bilinear interpolation.

As a prototype I coded it as shown below in Octave. It gives decent results. I am looking to get some reference on C implementation.

```
fid = fopen("anti_vig_gain_map.txt","r");
fid2 = fopen("ds_us_anti_vig_gain_map.txt","w");

for i=1:1968
    for j=1:2592
       map(i,j) = fscanf(fid,'%f\n',1);

    end
end

%downsample

ds_map = imresize(map,[8 8],'linear');

%% some processing on ds_map

%upsample

us_map = imresize(ds_map,[1968 2592],'linear');
```

I tried to see the code in imresize.m but it gets complicated after sometime and could not extract C code out of it.

Any pointers to reference C code for bilinear interpolation to perform the upsampling.

Also looking to get some pointers for the the anti-aliasing filter and down-sampling method using bilinear method.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is contained in the NetPBM suite.  Specifically, [pamscale](https://netpbm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/netpbm/trunk/editor/pamscale.c) which handles both up and down sampling with multiple possible filtering schemes for both directions.  The code is both well-written and self-contained.

Comment: I read that code, but it is - a)hard to understand and hence extract/modify. b)No way to test it.